# How to tell a javascript function what element to manipulate?

Tags: javascript, asp.net, css, web

I am so very new to `asp.net` and `javascript`, and I am supposed to do the following task in a couple of days. I know I have to learn all the basics, before asking, but really don't know where to get what I need in short time. Thanks a lot in advance!

Here's a number cities, which will be shown on a country map:
Each city has it's own style (since city positions are different), defined in a `css`.

```
<div class="node">
    <div class="taxonomy">
    </div>
    <div class="content">
        <div id="contact_map" runat="server">
            <ul>
                <li id="city1" onmouseover= "onmouseoveragent(this)"   
                               onmouseout="onmouseoutagent(this)">
                    <a href="someAddress"><span class="hideme">Some City Name</span>
                    </a>
                    <p class="hideme">Some City Name<strong class="tel">0123456789</strong>
                    </p>
                </li>
                <%-- other cities here, with different city name and tel --%>
            </ul>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

I will probably try to figure out how to create these city items dynamically later.

Below is a hint box, to be shown when mouse is over the city. It has to be repeated for all the cities. (**Question1:** How can I create these hint boxes dynamically, and somehow fill them with the information associated with the right city? Maybe I have to create the previous list dynamically, too..)

```
<div id="agentVisit" class="floating-tip-wrapper" style="margin: 0px; padding: 0px; position:    
    absolute; display:none; opacity: 1;">
    <div class="floating-tip" style="margin: 0px;">Some City Name
        <strong class="tel">0123456789</strong>
    </div>
</div>
```

And this is tha javascript code for `onmouseover` and `onmouseout` of each city: 
(**Question 2:** How can I tell the function which `agentVisit` to get? )

```
<script language="javascript" type="text/javascript">

    function onmouseoveragent(e) {
        var hint = document.getElementById("agentVisit");
        console.log(hint);
        hint.style.display = 'block';
        hint.style.top = Math.max(e.offsetTop - hint.offsetHeight, 0) + "px";
        hint.style.left = e.offsetLeft + "px";
    };

    function onmouseoutagent(e) {
        var hint = document.getElementById("agentVisit");
        hint.style.display = 'none';
    }

</script>
```

I would appreciate it if you provide an idea (or just a general hint) of how to do it. Or just a link to a quick tutorial. Thanks!

Comment: that's alot to work with.. have a fiddle?

Comment: yeah, I'm asking too much really. 
I don't have fiddle unfortunately.

Comment: Yes, that is not "Intro to JavaScript" material... if you try to learn that much JS + CSS + HTML in two days you might hurt yourself.  Try @Karl Anderson's suggestion.

Answer (score 0):

I think you are making this way more complicated than it has to be, because you can leverage data dash (`data-`) attributes of DOM elements and then use something like [jQueryUI Tooltip](http://jqueryui.com/tooltip/#default).